# httpd.conf missing from Apache2.2 package

Tags: php, apache, apache2.2

I have downloaded the Apache server msi file from [enter link description here](http://mirrors.sonic.net/apache//httpd/binaries/win32/). But there is no httpd.conf file anywhere in the package after installation. I am installing PHP for which I need to add some snippet of code from php --> install file to Apache --> httpd.cnf file. Searched everywhere but could not find.  Please somebody guide me.

My OS is 32bit - Windows 7 Home Premium

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the old Windows binaries on apache.org (currently 2.2.25 vs. 2.2.29 source distribution). You're much better off getting a current release from a third-party site like apachelounge.

Comment: do I need Visual Studio to install Apache